# Is there a way of copying only directories and not files?

Tags: scripting, directory, cp, suse

I want to copy only directories from a folder on a remote server to my server. Is that possible?
Here is the code I have so far but it copies files and folders:

```
scp -rq username@192.168.78.331:/copy/from/ /copy/it/here/
```

I also have an alternative for the code above:

```
ssh -q username@192.168.78.331 "cp -r /copy/from/ /copy/it/here/"
```

The problem is that both are copying the entire folder (including all folders and directories) from /copy/from/. Is there a way of only copying directories?

Comment: Do you want to copy attributes (ownership, permissions, acls, attributes...) of those directories?

Comment: I thought that is included when you are copying a directory?

Comment: Yes, but the thing that is also included when copying a directory are its directory entries - or the files it holds - which is sort of the directory's primary purpose. You can mirror a directory structure with commands like `mkdir -p` but I dunno about copying a directory without contents without deleting those contents afterward.

Comment: Are you open to other commands? rsync? if so check http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsdosx-copying-directory-structures-trees-rsync/

Comment: Instead of posting question after question on the same subject, why don't you post a question with the complete picture of what you're trying to do? You've now asked 9 questions related to this same subject.

Comment: As YoMismo points out, rsync can do that, but previously you've said you can't use rsync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just getting the structure and recreating it?

```
mkdir $( from=/copy/from;
         to=/copy/it/here;
         ssh -q username@192.168.78.331 "find $from -type d" \
         | sed "s=^$from/\?=$to/=" )
```

I used `sed` to remove the absolute path prefix and replace it with the target one. Test it with `echo` instead of `mkdir` to be sure it does what you want.

Also, I hope you don't use special characters in directory names.